# Loop only affecting index 0 any ideas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, loops

The idea is to change the content of `lbxcityTours.SelectedIndex i` if it matches string t1

```
string t1 = abcdefg;
int i = 0;
    while(i < lbxcityTours.Items.Count)
    {
        lbxcityTours.SelectedIndex = i;
         if (lbxcityTours.SelectedItem.ToString() == t1)
          {
            work.Text = lbxcityTours.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            lbxcityTours.SelectedItem.Value = "0";
            //remove the selected item from the listbox
            lstBoxAddedTours.Items.Remove(lstBoxAddedTours.SelectedItem);
           }
           i += 1;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have found the Item you should break out of the loop, otherwise you continue till the end of the Items collection and because you set the SelectedIndex at each loop you have only set the last item.

In any case I would not change the SelectedIndex (this could trigger the SelectedIndexChanged event and make difficult to track the flow of code) but I would work directly with the Items collection

```
string t1;
t1 = lstBoxAddedTours.SelectedItem.ToString();

int i = 0;
while (i < lbxcityTours.Items.Count)
{

    if (lbxcityTours.Items[i].Text == t1)
    {
        work.Text = i.ToString();                         
        lstBoxAddedTours.Items.Remove(lstBoxAddedTours.SelectedItem);
        lbxcityTours.Items[i].Value = "0";                     
        lstBoxAddedTours.SelectedIndex = -1;
        lbxcityTours.SelectedIndex = -1;
        break;
    }
    i +=1;
}
```

Comment: My overall intention is ,remove selected item from lbox2
change value of item in lbox1 which is the same as string t1 to ''0''

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. So, when you find the listbox item whose Value is equal to _t1_ you want to change this ListItem.Value to "0" and remove a ListItem in the _lstBoxAddedTours_ ? But if you want to remove a specific item in this second listbox you should find it as well unless the two listboxes contains the same items with the same order. In which case you could use the iteration variable _i_ to reach the required ListItem in the second ListBox (Of course this works only one time because the two ListBox are different after the remove)

Comment: I figure it out! It was the t1 string causing the issue. I wasn't updating its value when I selected different list items